# Basic .NET threading - Most efficient way to synchronize an object for a single reader and single writer thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, .net-2.0

I am using c# framework 2.0

I have an arraylist of objects. I need to make it thread safe for a single thread read and another single thread writer scenario.
The read happens a few hundred times every second while write (which involve removing or adding elements in the array) happen rarely, if ever, probably once a week from UI.

I can always use a lock() but how can I make this array threadsafe with minimum performance and latency overhead for reader thread.

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` instead of `List<object>` or `List<SpecificType>`?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Anyone coming across this, I encourage you to take a look at the discussion. The point about the reader thread modifying the objects in the array-list is very important to this whole class of questions about shared collections (and also why in this case I'd probably go with "just put a big lock on the whole thing" rather than the approach I give here without detailed analysis of those modifications. Still, the following can still work with some cases:

---

For the pattern of reads to writes that you describe, I would do the following.

Let's say the ArrayList is called `al`. For all reads, I would (mostly, see below) just read from ignoring all thread safety (don't worry, there's method in my madness). To write I would do:

```
ArrayList temp = new ArrayList(al);//create copy of al
/* code to update temp goes here */
al = temp;//atomic overwrite of al.
Thread.MemoryBarrier();//make sure next read of al isn't moved by compiler or from stale cache value.
```

The copying of `al` is safe, because ArrayList is safe for multiple readers. The assignment is safe because we're overwriting the reference, which is atomic. We just need to make sure there's a memory barrier though we could probably skip that in practice with most current system (don't though, theoretically at least it's required and let's not second-guess that).

This would be pretty dreadful for most shared use of an arraylist, because it makes the writes much more expensive than they have to be. However, those are as you say 60,000,000 times less frequent than the reads, so in this case that balance makes sense.

Note on safe reading with this approach:

I had made a false assumption because of thinking about a similar case.
The following is safe:

```
for(object obj in al)
  DoSomething(obj);
```

Even when `DoSomething` could take a long time. The reason is, that this calls `GetEnumerator()`  once and then works on an enumerator that will keep relating to the same list even if `al`  changes in the meantime (it'll be stale, but safe).

The following is not safe:

```
for(int i = 0; i < al.Count; ++i)
  DoSomething(al[i]);//
```

`Count` is safe, but it could be stale by the time you get to `al[i]` which could mean that you call `al[43]`  when `al` has only 20 items.

It's also safe to call `BinarySearch`, `Clone`, `Contains`, `IndexOf` and `GetRange`, but not safe to use the results of `BinarySearch`, `Contains` or `IndexOf` to decide upon a second thing you do with `al` because it could have changed by that time.

The following is also safe:

```
ArrayList list = al;
for(int i = 0; i != list.Count; ++i)
  DoSomething(list[i]);
DoSomethingElse(list);
DoSomethingReallyComplicated(list);
for(int i = 0; i != list.Count; ++i)
 SureWhyNotLetsLoopAgain(list[i]);
```

Note that we are not copying `al`, just copying the reference, so this is really really cheap. Everything we do with `list` is safe, because if it become stale, it's still one thread's own version of the old list and can't go wrong.

So. Either do everything in a `foreach` (the case I was mistakenly assuming), return the results of a single call to the methods noted as safe above (but don't use it to decide whether to do another operation on `al`), or assign `al` to a local variable and act on that.

---

Another **really** important caveat, is whether the writer thread will actually set any properties or call any non-threadsafe methods on any of the objects contained in the arraylist. If it does, then you've gone from having one thread synchronisation issue to think about, to having dozens!

If this is the case, then you have to worry about not just the arraylist, but each object that can be changed (by changed I mean the way calling `.Append("abc")` on a `StringBuilder` changes that object, not replacing with a completely new object the way `str = "abc"`  changes `str`).

There are four safe possibilities:

1. You have immutable objects in your arraylist - happy days.
2. You have mutable objects, but don't mutate them - good too, but you have to be *sure*.
3. You have threadsafe objects - okay, but that does mean you've at least one set of threading problems that is more complicated than the one this question deals with.
4. You lock on each object for both writing and reading - while locks being contested is less likely with such fine locks, this has its own heaviness and really you're no better than the default (and it should be the default) answer of "just lock, locks are cheap when not contested anyway).

Comment: NB: This assumes every detail of what you said above was correct. It does a lot of things against conventional wisdom as an optimisation to the specifics of the case.

Comment: The code you wrote goes into the reader thread routine that reads the arraylist? If this is the case then doing a "new" is too expensive for me as it gets called a lot.

Comment: I am wondering, since write involves removing and adding elements inside arraylist and hence changing the list.Count, the for loop in the reader part that loops on list.Count can throw an exception for collection modified or index changed...or you think your logic will take care of that also?

Comment: ...there, updated to detail just what is and isn't safe for the reader to do in this situation.
Still, it does stand as a warning to trying this approach (one day you slip in an unsafe case forgetting about the other thread). It's for when you really, really need it. Well, that and for when you go on stackoverflow.com to look for interesting questions :)

Comment: ok, so in my case the writer only adds/removes the objects in the list without modifying the objects themselves. The reader does modify the objects contained within the arraylist but does'nt modify the list itself. The objects contained within are mutable. So you still think doing a foreach in reader thread is safe? In my case processing stale list is not a big issue as it will only happen once but it has to be safe and has to be fast.

Comment: foreach is safe because internally it creates an enumerator object on the reader thread and then works from that from then on. I'm more worried about your comment "the reader does modify the objects contained". This means your "reader" is actually a writer to objects that the "writer" is reading! It **may** still work with the above, but without a lot more info on those objects, I'd have to say it probably won't. You've really got two writer threads doing different sorts of writing, which is not the single-reader/single-writer case I was answering above.

Comment: ok, looks like I will have to do some testing but the writer thread in this case does not modify the actual object, it only add or remove them from the list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5830/discussion-between-jon-hanna-and-bsobaid)

Answer (score 3):

Since there is only reader and one writer, a `ReaderWriterLock` would not help in this case. Probably the classic `lock` is the best option in this case.

Having said this, since the reader needs to read very often and thus checks the lock often, a robust solution would be a SpinLock: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock.aspx

**Edit**: Indeed, as pointed out by David Silva, `SpinLock` is not available in .net 2.0. However, it can be implemented with repeated calls to `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, but probably going into details is not relevant at this stage. The classic `lock` is your best option.

Comment: Looks like the SpinLock is only available in Framework 4 and he is looking for a framework 2.0 solution. Not sure if he could use reflector to create a framework 2.0 of the SpinLock class?

Comment: I linked more for reference as to how it works. It can be implemented with repeated calls to Interlocked.CompareExchange.

Comment: Creating a good SpinLock has a few gotchas. I recall Joe Duffy writing something good on them. Still, I don't think any locking on reading is necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a `lock`. If it's uncontended, it is very fast - certainly capable of millisecond periods.

Answer (score 1):

I went through this process recently.  It turns out the performance gain on a lockless version of single-producer/consumer queue is almost meaningless (around 0.0002 ms per queue/dequeue).

My advice is to just use the lock() statement, it works.  You may also look at the lockless version i wrote, see [Writing a Lockless Queue for a single producer/consumer](http://csharptest.net/460/writing-a-lockless-queue-for-a-single-producerconsumer-part-3/).  The last article in the series has a [locking queue](http://csharptest.net/465/writing-a-lockless-queue-for-a-single-producerconsumer-part-4/) you could also use.

Comment: It's not a producer/consumer queue though, it's a shared collection.

Comment: @Jon Hanna, The OPs statement "I need to make it thread safe for a single thread read and another single thread writer scenario..."  leads me to believe that the code linked to in the above article could be modified to suite his needs.  Agreed it's not a perfect match, but just a starting point if he insists on travelling that road.  Again my advice is to just use the lock() statement.

Comment: I don't agree because the surface of an arraylist-like structure is much more complicated than with a queue. You can create a lockless version, but it's nowhere near as simple as with a queue (or a stack - queues and stacks are probably the two easiest containers to make lockless). And even there, "simple" and "easy" relative - there's still plenty to think about in those two cases.